# Find common factors of three rounded integers

Tags: systems-of-equations, factoring, integers

I'm trying to find the common factor(s) of three integers which have each been rounded up to the next multiple of 8:

- i = round(n * a)
- j = round(n * b)
- k = round(n * c)

I'm given i, j, and k and I'm trying to find n. The rounding for all three is always to the next multiple of 8.

I could probably handle the simultaneous equation or finding the factor(s) on my own, but I'm a programmer and not a mathematician and don't know how to handle the complication added with the rounding mathematically. (Stackoverflow said I should ask the question here though.)

---

Real-world example:

i = 33475329 * 8, a = 42
j = 21519854 * 8, b = 27
k = 18331728 * 8, c = 23

n = 6376253

Comment: What does "round(n*a)" mean? How do $a$, $b$ and $c$ fit into this?

Comment: To be clear, $i$ is the greatest multiple of $8$ greater than or equal to $a$, $j$ is the greatest multiple of $8$ greater than or equal to $b$, and $k$ is the greatest multiple of $8$ greater than or equal to $c$, right? It would also be much more helpful if we got the full context. Does this have to do with bytes or file sizes or something like that? What exactly are you trying to do? What is the purpose of finding the common factor? All of this info would really help us figure out how to help you better.

Comment: hippie. the thing that might work is for you to edit in two or three examples of what you want to happen.

Comment: In any case, if you are a programmer, I feel like brute force might be the easiest solution since the remainders of $a,b,c$ are only within $0$ and $7$, so only $8^3=512$ iterations are needed to test all possibilities of $a,b,c$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Yes I posited the brute force solution on the original SO version of the question but thought I could be missing interesting insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983150/finding-the-common-factor-of-three-integers-each-multiplied-by-independent-integ

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Yes I have three files which are "bit packed arrays" where each array has the same number of elements but the number of bits per element is not known. Though I do know they must be <= 53 bits, they're typically in the 20s-30s. Files of course can only have even byte sizes. I have expressed the problem in number of bits by considering filesize*8 for each of i, j, k; but it's possible to consider it in number of bytes too - I just thought that would be harder.

Comment: @JohnDouma: round() is a function that rounds the integer up to the next closest multiple of 8. Sorry that I am ignorant if there is a good way to express this mathematically. To put it another way, round() will add some integer between 0 and 7 inclusive so that i, j, and k are guaranteed to be exact multiples of 8.

Comment: @hippietrail For any $i$, $j$, and $k$, is $n=1$, $a=i$, $b=j$ and $c=k$ a solution?

Comment: @WillJagy: I've added an example.

Comment: Just, so you know, the best way to express rounding up to the nearest multiple of $8$ is $8\lceil \frac{na}{8} \rceil$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think we basically have to assume $a,b,c$ are coprime in order to find $n$. Otherwise, you run into the problem [Ross Millikan pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057444/307483) where $n$ is ambiguous and depends on knowing the common factor between $a,b,c$. Thus, the rest of this solution is going to assume $a,b,c$ are coprime. For example, if the choice is between $(a,b,c)=(46, 18, 54)$ and $(a,b,c)=(23, 9, 27)$, we will choose the latter.

Honestly, I still think the brute force solution is the easiest way to do this. However, I have found a slightly faster solution, although it requires more precomputation. First, I will assume $n$ is very big, so the change from $na$ to $i$, which is just $na$ rounded up to the nearest multiple of $8$, is a very small percent change. For instance, in your example, $i$ is $267802632$ while $na$ is $267802626$, which is a percent change in about $.000002\%$, which is quite small indeed.

Therefore, because of these small percent changes, the ratios between $i,j,k$ are very similar to the ratios between $na,nb,nc$. For instance, in your example $\frac i j$ is $1.5555555813715094$ while $\frac{na}{nb}$ is $1.5555555555555556$, which are very close to each other. However, $\frac{na}{nb}$ simplifies to $\frac a b$, so we get:
$$\frac i j\approx \frac a b$$
Now, we know the ratio between $a$ and $b$. However, how do we solve for $a$ and $b$ based off this ratio? Since $a,b\leq 53$, the easiest way to do this is to make an array of all possible ratios $\frac l m$ for $l,m\leq 53$ and do a binary search for $\frac i j$ to find what $a$ and $b$ should be.

Now, from here, finding $n$ is easy: $i\approx na$, so $n\approx \frac i a$. Since we know $n$ is an integer, we can just say $n=\lceil \frac i a \rceil$ and call it a day. Once we know $n$, finding $c$ is also easy: $k\approx nc$, so $c\approx \frac k n\rightarrow c=\lceil \frac k n\rceil$. Thus, we have found $n$, $a$, $b$, and $c$, so we are done.

There is one ambiguity to this, however: If the ratio between $a$ and $b$ has small numerator and denominator, like $\frac 3 4$, how do we know if the solution is $(a,b)=(3,4)$ or $(a,b)=(6,8)$? Now, because we want $a,b,c$ to be coprime, but this does not necessarily mean $a,b$ are coprime. For instance, in your example, $a,b,c$ are coprime, but $a,b$ has common factor of $3$. Therefore, when we find $n$ and $c$, we need to test that $i,j,k$ are indeed $na,nb,nc$ rounded up to the nearest integer and if they are not, we need to multiply $a,b$ by some common factor in order to test if that new common factor leads to a new value of $n$ and $c$ which works. Again, using your example, this means we will first test $(a,b)=(14,9)$, then $(a,b)=(28,18)$, then $(a,b)=(42,27)$ before finally getting the correct solution.

Using all of this analysis, we can construct the following solution:

```
import math
import bisect

# This array holds all ratios l/m where 1 <= l,m <= 53 and l,m are coprime
ratios = []
for l in range(1, 54):
    for m in range(1, 54):
        if math.gcd(l, m) == 1:
            ratios.append((l/m, l, m))
# Sort the ratios into increasing order:
ratios = sorted(ratios)

def compute_nabc(i, j, k):
    '''
    This function computes the values of n, a, b, and c
    based off the values of i, j, and k.
    '''
    # Find the index where i/j would be put in the ratios array
    ij_index = bisect.bisect(ratios, (i/j, i, j))
    # error_on_left is the absolute difference between i/j
    # and the greatest ratio in ratios less than i/j
    error_on_left = math.inf
    if ij_index-1 > 0:
        error_on_left = abs(i/j-ratios[ij_index-1][0])
    # error_on_right is the absolute difference between i/j
    # and the least ratio in ratios greater than i/j
    error_on_right = math.inf
    if ij_index < len(ratios):
        error_on_right = abs(i/j-ratios[ij_index][0])
    # If the error_on_left is less, take a and b from the lesser ratio:
    if error_on_left < error_on_right:
        smallest_a = ratios[ij_index-1][1]
        smallest_b = ratios[ij_index-1][2]
    # Otherwise, take a and b from the greater ratio:
    else:
        smallest_a = ratios[ij_index][1]
        smallest_b = ratios[ij_index][2]
    # Notice how the above variables are named smallest_a and smallest_b.
    # This is because they are the values of a, b which are coprime.
    # However, it is possible that a, b have some common factor d,
    # so let's loop through d:
    # (Given a,b <= 53, the greatest possible common factor is 53/2=26.)
    for d in range(1, 27):
        # Compute a and b by multiplying d by the smallest_a and smallest_b:
        a = d*smallest_a
        b = d*smallest_b
        # i is about na, so n is about i/a:
        n = round(i/a)
        # k is about nc, so c is about k/n:
        c = round(k/n)

        # Now, at the end here, we are simply verifying that
        # i, j, k are indeed na, nb, nc rounded up to the nearest integer.
        # If not, then we continue to the next value of d.
        if i != 8*math.ceil(n*a/8): pass
        elif j != 8*math.ceil(n*b/8): pass
        elif k != 8*math.ceil(n*c/8): pass
        # Otherwise, if everything's good, we exit
        else: break

        # If d is 26 and we never found an answer, print error message
        if d == 26:
            print("ERROR: Valid answer not found")

    # Finally, return n, a, b, and c in a 4-tuple
    return (n, a, b, c)

# Outputs (6376253, 42, 27, 23)
print(compute_nabc(33475329*8, 21519854*8, 18331728*8))
# Outputs (201720, 23, 9, 27)
print(compute_nabc(579945*8, 226935*8, 680805*8))
# Outputs (38587389, 33, 23, 45)
print(compute_nabc(159172980*8, 110938744*8, 217054064*8))
# Outputs (6371253, 52, 26, 33)
print(compute_nabc(41445645*8, 20722823*8, 26302044*8))
```

Now, the pre-computation is about $53^2=2809$ operations, which is slower than brute force of $512$ operations. However, the actual `compute_nabc` function only takes $\lceil \log_2(2809)\rceil=12$ comparisons for binary search and about $26\cdot 4=$ operations, at most, for testing the different possible values of $n,c$, so the actual `compute_nabc` function is about $5$ times less operations than brute force. Thus, although it might not make an actual difference since brute force is still pretty fast, if you are OK with doing a lot of pre-computation and have to execute `compute_nabc` dozens or hundreds of times, it might be easier to use this approach than brute force.

Comment: What an amazing, thorough, and understandable answer and analysis! I've tried the brute force on the example I gave and it works great. I'll try it on my other datasets after the holidays. I was aware of the edge cases with coprimes etc but perhaps not fully. I intended to deal with those using various heuristics which I thought was beyond the scope of the maths site, which is why I originally posted the question on StackOverflow. Sadly it's been attacked over there. You are a lot more helpful and welcoming here.

Comment: @hippietrail Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't with the data you are given.  Let $a,b,c$ be close, say $b=a+1, c=a+2$ and $n$ be $4$.  You can't tell from the case where $n$ is $2$ and the others are doubled.